# Laravel 5: Password Reset - move bcrypt password to User.php model?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I noticed that some developers modify PasswordController.php so that the method **resetPassword($user, $password)** does not *bcrypt* password. Instead, the password is *bcrypt*ed in model **User.php**.

Here is an example of that: *app/Http/Controllers/Auth/***PasswordController.php**:

```
<?php

namespace SundaySlim\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use SundaySlim\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class PasswordController extends Controller
{

   use ResetsPasswords;

  public function __construct()
  {
      $this->redirectTo = route('backend.dashboard');
      $this->middleware('guest');
  }

  protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
  {
     $user->password = $password;
     $user->save();
     auth()->login($user);
  }
}
```

As you can see, there is resetPassword($user, $password) method copied from  *vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/* **ResetPasswords.php**. It is modified so that there is no *bcrypt*ing password.

Here's how this method originally looked like:

```
protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
{
    $user->password = bcrypt($password);

    $user->save();

    Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($user);
}
```

(also, as you can see - *Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($user);* is changed to *auth()->login($user);*)

The idea is to create a mutator in model **Users.php** in which password will be *bcrypt*ed.

So, here is the model **User.php** with that mutator:

```
<?php

namespace SundaySlim;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

**1.** What would be the reason to do something like that (to create a mutator in **Users.php** to *bcrypt* password AND NOT in **resetPassword($user, $password)** as it is by default)? Why would move bcrypting password from **resetPassword($user, $password)**  to User.php model, is there some practical reason to do such a thing?

**2.** What is the difference between: **auth()->login($user);** and **Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($user);** ?

By the way, here is the **routes.php**:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('backend/dashboard', [
        'uses'=>'Backend\DashboardController@index',
        'as'=>'backend.dashboard'
    ]);

    Route::controller('auth', 'Auth\AuthController', [
        'getLogin' => 'auth.login',
        'getLogout' => 'auth.logout'
    ]);

    Route::controller('auth/password', 'Auth\PasswordController', [
        'getEmail' => 'auth.password.email',
        'getReset' => 'auth.password.reset' 
    ]);
});
```

Comment: In answer to question 1: having a mutator for the password that encrypts it, prevents a developer from bypassing the controller method and failing to encrypt the password - they can't just set a plain text password on the model & save it.

Comment: Imagine I'm a developer who writes the following code: `$user->password = 'something';  $user->save();`. If there is a mutator, that password will be encrypted in the user model before saving. If there is no mutator, that password will be saved as plain text in the database.

Comment: @Kryten Aha, I understand now. I wonder why Laravel does not have such mutator in its User.php model by default, but we need to modify PasswordController.php (to remove bcrypt from, for example, resetPassword($user, $password) and to create mutator in model...

Answer (score 1):

Another answer to question 1:

You can register a custom UserProvider so that you can override the database part of Laravel's security implementation. I spent a bit of time today implementing authentication against a legacy database, where the passwords are stored as md5 hashes of the supplied password. This was done by registering a custom UserProvider, and from an authentication perspective it works well.

Using bcrypt and then setting the password is an architectural problem in Laravel as this assumes that the custom UserProvider will store bcrypt hashes for passwords. Replacing this hardwired logic with a mutator places the logic in the right place - custom UserProviders can now load and store authentication data however they need. In general it is invasive to dictate how passwords are encrypted, even with the out-of-the-box security implementation.

The problem with the above-mentioned override of PasswordController::resetPassword($user, $password) is that it involves reverse engineering of internal logic - it wastes time hunting down and replacing the errant behaviour, and the workaround can stop working at any time that the internal logic changes.

FYI there is another less invasive hack to get around this. Before setting the new password, UserProvider::retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials) is called to validate and load the user for whom the password is being reset. The $credentials array contains the new plaintext password only on password reset, so you can cache the password as an attribute during the password reset flow. On UserProvider::save(), ignore the bcrypt hash and use the cached password instead. This does mean that you have to have an AuthUser that is separate from the actual user model though.